# computing argument of $w = -1 + i$

Tags: complex-numbers

So i'm computing the argument of the following complex number: w = -1 + i. It's modulus, |w|, is sqrt(2). I draw a diagram of w. It is a triangle in the second quadrent: [image: enter As shown here].

I find that Phi is 3pi/4 which seems to agree with the solution I am shown, but shouldn't I have to calculuate theta instead of Phi? Did I calculuate Phi incorrectly?

Comment: I can't follow your work at all, but in your picture $\theta = 3\pi /4$, while $\phi = \pi / 4$.  Note that $3 \pi /4 = 135^\circ$.

Comment: @mathmandan In my picture I did the following: $\tan(-1) = \phi$, $\implies \tan^{-1}(\phi) = -1$, $\implies \phi = \frac{3\pi}{4}$. Why is $\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$ ?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That is not very helpful. My question more pertains to the geometry of the question. Or, I do not understand your link.

Comment: Imagine for a minute that your picture was reflected across the $y$-axis, so the triangle was in the first quadrant. Presumably you'll agree that the triangle is a 45-45-90 triangle. But its angles are the same if you draw it in Quadrant II instead. So $\phi = 45^\circ = \pi / 4$.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now. Thank you @mathmandan. My question is now resolved. If you wish to post your comments as an answer, I will happily approve them for the answer of this question. Though, I do wonder how I was able to arrive at the same answer of $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ despite my incorrect approach. Perhaps you could explain that?

Comment: I think you are just mixing up theta and phi.  The smaller angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is phi and the larger angle $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ is theta... Which is the argument of $-1 + i$.